# Need help using setters and getters

Tags: java, getter-setter

I am very new to setters and getters. I am working on a simple program to try and get better at using them. I have two classes and all i am trying to do is make an account for a random person, setting a balance and withdrawing from it.I don't think i used the setters and getters properly and if someone could steer me in the right direction I would be very appreciative.

```
package SetterGettersPractice;

public class account {
private String name;
public double balance =0;
public double withdraw;
public double deposit;
public double getDeposit() {
    return deposit;
}

public void setDeposit(double deposit) {
    this.deposit = deposit;
}

public account(String name, double d){

    this.name = name;
    this.balance = d;
}

private double sumDeposits(){
    balance = balance + deposit;
    return balance;
}
private double sumWithdrawals(){
    balance = balance - withdraw;
    return balance;
}
public double getwithdraw() {
    return withdraw;
}

public void setwithdraw(double withdraw) {
    this.withdraw = withdraw;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}
public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
public String toString(){

    return "Name="+name+" balance="+balance;
}
```

}

and this is my other class

```
package SettersGettersPractice;

public class testAccount {

public static void test1(){

    account a = new account("John Doe", 100);
    a.withdraw(10.0);
    System.out.print("Balance %d", balance);
}
}
```

As you can see, I plan on trying to expand on the program once I figure out what I am doing. Any advice to help a noob out would be awesome!

Comment: Where did you declare `balance` here --> `System.out.print("Balance %d", balance);`? `a.withdraw(10.0);` --> The `account` class has no `withdraw` method.

Comment: "I don't think i used the setters and getters properly"  Why do you think that?  Are you getting an error message when you try to compile the code?  What is the message?  Which line of the code does the message mention?  What exactly are you asking us to help you do?

Comment: i think i messed up on the testAccount class, i'm getting an undefined error for the withdraw(10.0);

Comment: "undefined error?" what is that?  What is the _actual error message_?  Put it in your question.  P.S.:  I can't help noticing that your `account` class does not have a method named `withdraw`.

Comment: @irradiatedcat Hello. Did any of the answers below answer your question? Do you have any further questions?

Comment: Partially, i am still having difficulty printing the balance. I tried the ones below but receive error messages.

Comment: @irradiatedcat Paste your entire code into http://pastebin.com/ and send me the link as a comment to my answer. I will help you.

Comment: @Connorelsea http://pastebin.com/RD8U1xhC

Comment: @irradiatedcat What error message are you getting?

Comment: not getting one right now, now im trying to figure out how to deposit

Comment: @irradiatedcat Well maybe make a deposit method that takes a double, and then inside of that method it adds the argument's amount to the already existing balance variable. Also, if one of the answers below sufficiently answered your question, please mark it ask correct using the check mark below the arrows.

Comment: @irradiatedcat Oh wow haha that wasn't my answer... Sucks to help and then get no recognition. Oh well. Good luck to you.

Comment: @Connorelsea oops, i accidentally hit the wrong answer, my bad. i fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why getters and setters?**

You are using them fairly correctly, with a few mistakes. Getters and setters are meant to provide **encapsulation** of your data.

For example, let's say you have a "Dog" class that has a "weight" variable

```
public class Dog {
    int weight;
}
```

Current, you could create a new instance of the Dog object, and edit it's weight variable like this:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.weight = 45;
```

Though logical, this practice opens up the possibility for wrong values to be set, possibly messing up the entire program. For example, with this set up, someone could set the weight variable to a negative number, which would not make sense

```
dog.weight = -50;
```

**How to create a setter method?**

To prevent this from happening, you can make the weight variable in the Dog class **private** instead of public.

```
public class Dog {
    private int weight;
}
```

Now if you tried to access that variable at all, from outside of the class, it would be blocked.

```
dog.weight = 45; // would result in an error
```

So, how do you let them access it again, but not provide a wrong value? You encapsulate its data with a setter!

```
public class Dog {
    private int weight;

    public void setWeight(int i) {
        this.weight = i;
    }
}
```

**How to encapsulate (protect your data) with setters?**

This is the creation of a setter. But to ensure it's data is correct, you would do the following:

```
public class Dog {
    int weight;

    public void setWeight(int i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            this.weight = i;
        } else {
            System.out.println("A dog can't have negative weight!");
        }
    }
}
```

**How to create a getter method?**

And, since this data is private, this means that they cannot use it in any way, even to display it, so to **retrieve** this variable's value from the object, you would create a **getter** method.

```
public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
```

**How to use/fire getters and setters in your code?**

Now to change variables for your "Dog" object with these getters and setters in place, you would do:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.setWeight(45);
System.out.println(dog.getWeight());
```

If you have any further questions, just ask in the comments and I will be sure to explain!

Answer (score 0):

Make the data members private and you'll be ok. Also, you may want to get your code formatting better - convention says class names should be capitalized: `Account` vs `account`.

The methid `setwithdraw` should not be setter. It contains more advanced logic, so I'd rather call it `withdraw`.

Answer (score 0):

your class does not have any method named `withdraw` also in your  test method there is no variable names `balance`.

I would call methods i have defined in my class to properly set and get values like following

```
package SettersGettersPractice;

public class testAccount {

public static void test1(){

    account a = new account("John Doe", 100);
    a.setwithdraw(10.0);
    System.out.print("Balance %d", a.sumWithdrawals());
}
}
```

while above code can give me expected output, I would consider renaming my class to Account(naming conventions) also i would rename `setwithdraw` to `withdraw` and `sumWithdrawals` to `getBalance` based on the functionality implemented in them. I advise that you read [Basics of java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) which includes naming conventions, code conventions etc. then start coding.

Answer (score 0):

your code should rather like this if u want to use getters and setters you need to run them so:

```
 account a = new account("John Doe", 100);
    a.setBalance(10.0);

    System.out.print(a.getBalance);
```

Simple as that:)

P.S. Class names ALWAYS starts with big first letter!

Comment: `getBalance` would be undefined in your code snippet.